# "It means" + "to [infinitive]" or "[gerund]"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, infinitive-vs-gerund

In a sentence *"Something means* `X`*"*, where `X` is a verb (i.e. an action), should I use the gerund or the form "to + infinitive"? Is there a difference between them?

Example:

> Helping your mom means **to do** chores from time to time
>   Helping your mom means **doing** chores from time to time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Helping your mom means **to do** chores from time to time=**NO**

2) Helping your mom **means doing** chores from time to time=**YES**

Sentence 1) is not grammatical. Form: Doing something + means + gerund [etc.]

The meaning of ***means***  here is: implies or calls for. That is the semantic meaning of the verb ***mean*** in this sentence.

Sentence 2) Not grammatical at all. There is another meaning of the verb ***mean*** that is: to intend to do something. ***I intend to so something*** can be expressed as ***I mean to do something***.

If we rewrite sentence 1) with the meaning of the verb mean that means to ***intend to do something***, we can see it would not make sense:

- Helping your mom **intends to do** chores from time to time=**NO**. That's easy to see.

Now, here's an example with: mean + to-infinitive.

- ***I mean (intend) to finish this explanation*** before I go food shopping.

I hope that clarifies the issue for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what's the correct example? It seems the "=YES" indicates it's correct, but then "Sentence 2) Not grammatical at all.".