# To make vs making

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

> The mission of my life from now onwards **is making** my parents proud.

Vs

> The mission of my life from now onwards **is to make** my parents proud.

Which form is correct ? The gerund form or the infinitive form?
And what is the main verb here?

Comment: When asking a compare-and-contrast question like this one, the sentences you are asking about should be put in a "quote box", and the differences between the two should be bolded. Now that you've asked over 50 questions, it's time to stop relying on other community members to make those edits for you. There is a [helpful post on meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783) that can give you insights into basic Stack Exchange formatting tricks. P.S. As far as your question goes, I think either one of those forms would be acceptable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["It means" + "to \[infinitive\]" or "\[gerund\]"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/134165/it-means-to-infinitive-or-gerund)

Answer (score 0):

First one is more suitable for this case of sentences..

> the mission of my life from now on is making my parents proud

means you are not doing it before, you've just decided to at that moment. This sentence is OK.

> the mission of my life from now on is to make my parents proud.

is a bit off, because **to make** is a general verb that implies a long-term, ongoing action (You've done it before, you doing' it now, and you will do it again).

Maybe you have to modified the second sentence to this one by removing the **from now on**:

> The mission of my life is to make my parents proud.

Sound more relevant. it's general mission that implies a long-term, ongoing mission that you do

That is my opinion.
but in everyday conversation, dont think anybody will care... people get the message already with either one, But the first sentence is more suitable for carrying the message

Comment: In my view "to make" may or may not imply"ong-term, ongoing action " depending on the context, and the conclusion in this answer is not valid. Consider "*Before he could serve the meal, he needed **to make** a pot of rice*" Here "to make" is used for a one-time event.

Answer (score 0):

The two sentences

> - The mission of my life from now onwards **is making** my parents proud.
> - The mission of my life from now onwards **is to make** my parents proud.

are effectively interchangeable, and I don't see any difference of meaning that would be reliably understood by fluent speakers, not even a nuance. Both are valid and sound natural to me. The difference is one of style.

Personally I prefer the second form, using the infinitive, but that is just a matter of my taste.

Also, at least in US usage "from now onwards" is a bit unusual. One would almost always say (and hear) "from now on" instead.

[This Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=from+now+on%2Cfrom+now+onwards&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) shows that "from now on" is indeed far more common. Using the "British" corpus, the two were similar in frequency prior to 1925, but even in that corpus "from now on" has held a significant lead since about 1930, and "from now onwards" has been steadily dropping in frequency since 1942. in the overall English-language corpus "from now on" has appeared at least 10 times as often ever since 1882.

Note that the Google Ngrams measure usage in books published in a given year, and may not always show current usage in that year. Older works and books that quote old texts may distort frequencies, and what is used in books may not match what is used in newspapers or speech. But when the difference is as marked as in this case, I think it is worth noting.

I would advise avoiding "from now onwards" in ordinary writing or speech.